# JAVA: Programa que lee un entero y una posicion

Tags: java

Me dieron un ejercicio para que en Java haga un programa que lea un entero de varias cifras y una posicion; y luego muestre por pantalla la cifra del numero que esta en la posicion indicada. Por ejemplo, para el numero 1234 la posicion 1 deberia devolver el valor 4, la 2: 3, la 3:2, la 4:1.
 Puedo hacerlo para una determinada cantidad de cifras sin problema, pero necesito que el programa pueda tomar cualquier entero de cualquier cantidad de digitos y mostrar lo que se pide. Solo se me ocurrio dividir al numero por 10^posicion dada y luego descartar el resto, el problema con esto es que no se como hacer potencias en java y solo he visto estructuras alternativas hasta ahora.
 Este es el codigo que utilice para 3 cifras, no veo como hacerlo para mas cifras sin usar potencias.

```
 public static int cifraInt(int numero,int posicion){
  //Modulo que lee un entero y su posicion y retorna el digito que se encuentra
  //en la posicion elegida
  int cent, dec, uni, digito;
  cent= numero/100;
  dec=numero/10-cent*10;
  uni=numero-cent*100-dec*10;
  switch (posicion){
      case 1: digito=cent;
      break;
      case 2: digito=dec;
      break;
      case 3: digito= uni;
      break;
      default: digito=-1;
  }
  return digito;
```

Comment: Deberias de poner el codigo de lo que has intentado para que sea mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Agregue el codigo para 3 cifras, podria hacerlo de otra forma mas simple pero necesitaria usar potencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola nose si te ayuden estos datos:

1.-existe algo llamado modulo que te entrega el resto de una division y funcionas asi:

```
int resto = 634 % 10;
System.out.println("resto :"+resto);
```

el resultado es 4.

2.-para hacer la potencia de un numero quizas lo podrias hacer asi:

```
int base=10;
int exponente=3;
for(int j=1;j<exponente;j++){
    base=base*10;//potencia de base 10
}
System.out.println("10 elevado a "+exponente+" es "+base);
```

3.-para saber cuantos digitos tiene el numero ingresado usando el ciclo for :

```
int cantDeDigitos = 1;
for(int i=1;i<=numero;i++){            
   cantDeDigitos = i;
   numero = numero / 10;                        
}
System.out.println("numero con "+cantDeDigitos+" digito/os");
```

ojala te sirva exito!!

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Pense usar modulo pero desafortunadamente siempre voy a necesitar hacer un ciclo de ese tipo ("for") para resolver este problema, o tener una potencia importando una libreria.

Answer (score 1):

¿Y por qué, no hacerlo mucho mas simple, decirle al número que se transforme en un `string`, después partirlo en pedacitos,  y devolver ese pedacito?

Digamos, algo así:

```
public static int cifraInt(int numero,int posicion){
    String arr[] = String.valueOf(numero).split("");
    return arr[posicion];
}
```

Lo único que habría que controlar, es que la posición no esté por fuera de la cantidad de dígitos que tiene el número. Con un `if`, antes del `return`, se podría solucionar fácil.

También, tené en cuenta que el array está indexado en cero, así que en realidad, deberías mirar la posición `-1`.

Comment: Como nota al margen, tambien se puede hacer con una funcion recursiva, y con un for que lea el primer digito y divida...

Comment: Debe ser una buena idea, pero la verdad no se que es un array. En el curso hasta ahora solo vimos estructuras alternativas (como if y switch). Si solo tuviera una forma de potenciar o repetir la multiplicacion por 10 un numero "posicion" de veces podria realizar el programa.

Comment: hijo, con esto vas a aprender de lo más bonito: http://tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/ un arreglo es una estructura de datos que comienza en índice CERO (muy importante). http://tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=16&codigo=89&inicio=0 Este es el tema relacionado a lo que menciona el hermano @gbianchi

Comment: Entonces tendrias que aclarar que queres y como lo queres. soluciones hay montones, pero si tenes restricciones es todo muy diferente @TIKINNI

Comment: @gbianchi Es que hasta ahora solo vimos lo que dije en la pregunta, estructuras secuenciales y las alternativas. Creo que hay una forma de simular una potencia usando algo que veremos la clase siguiente que creo es "for" o algo asi; pero estaba buscando la forma de hacerlo usando esos temas nomas, ya que son los que mas o menos entiendo bien. Muchisimas gracias por sus comentarios igual!

Comment: no se que es una estructura secuencial, y si no sabes lo que es una iteracion (un for o while) dificil que podamos ayudarte entonces, salvo con un codigo totalmente inusable. la funcion de potenciacion es math.pow, pero tampoco te va a servir, porque deberias iterar (que decis que no sabes) sobre los caracteres, para saber que valor usar. @TIKINNI